# Output PHP string to show escaped characters

Tags: php

In PHP, is it at all possible to output the contents of a string to show any escaped characters that may be contained within the string? I get that the whole point of escaping characters is so that they aren't treated in the usual way. But I would still like to be able to view the raw contents of a string so I can see for myself exactly how characters like \n and \r, etc. are represented. Does PHP have a method for doing this?

Comment: I should have specified in my question that my string is contained within a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the string as JSON. The JSON encoding of strings (which is, in fact, JavaScript) is the same as the one used by PHP. Both JavaScript and PHP were inspired from C and they copied the notation of string literals from it.

Answer (score -3):

if you use single quotation marks it should do what you need

eg `echo 'this\n';` will output this\n where as `echo "this\n";` will output this and a new line

Comment: My string is contained within a variable, so if I echo the variable within single quotes, it just returns the variable name. E.g. echo '$inpQuestion' gives $inpQuestion